# Java: How can i avoid ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException while stress testing

Tags: java, spring, jpa, locking

i have a little wicket application where users can log in.
When they login a log is written in the database. Before persisting, the rows are counted and thats where the exception comes from when i run the stress test with 30 users logging in and out simultaneously.

This countig and persisting takes place in a Spring-DAO annotated with @Transactional also there is a connection pool. The counting method looks like this:

```
private long getLogSize() {
    final CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    final Root<UserLog> userLog = cq.from(UserLog.class);
    cq.select(cb.count(userLog ));
    return query.getSingleResult();
}
```

So how can i lock the table and prevent the race condition? Setting the query to setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ) does not work, only i get this: MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction.

Comment: Have you tried to annotate your persisting method with LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE?